# How to create replicas of domino databases having readers fields?

Tags: replication, lotus-domino

I have created replica of a database which has some documents with readers field using admin client. the replica has been created properly except for the documents having readers field.

The only way we could figure out to replicate these documents with readers fields is to get the “Full Access Administration” using domino admin & then creating the replica from client (right click->create replica).
Though this approach is working, it’s not feasible for us considering the huge db sizes (some more than 15 GB).

Is there a way we can achieve the replication of the documents having readers fields through admin process?

Comment: Does the server has read right on thoses docs? Could you afford shuting down the domino server and copy the nsf the DB ?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the servers involved in the replication are part of the readers field.

A very common way to achieve this is to add a role to the readers fields (e.g. [Admin]) and then add this role to the ACL so that all servers have this role.

[image]

Comment: This is a legacy application without any any specific role or server id added in reader's field.

Comment: This explains why the server is not able to replicate these documents